# Shopify PHP App: api/auth don't run when installing my App in first time

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I build an application by PHP/Lavarel for Shopify, based on this code:  shopify-app-template-php

But now, I install my app by: click to App -> Test your app -> Select Store -> Create new Store -> (I create new store with data).. -> Install my App.

But in fact, there are only 1 function in web/routes/web.php can run for FIRST TIME:

Route::fallback(function (Request $request)

There are 2 importants functions WILL NOT be trigger:

Route::get('/api/auth', function (Request $request)
Route::get('/api/auth/callback', function (Request $request)

I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY?

---

Then, I choose my this store, uninstall my App, then re-install this App. Everything is ok! 3 below functions are triggered and my App can be installed successfully!

---

What wrong with my journey below when I trying FIRST time installing? Any advice from you? Thank you very much..